# How to check intersection for n number of controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a Winforms C# application which allows users to locate objects on a scrollable area by moving them by mouse actions. Both Scrollable area and objects are panel controls.

Users places objects on the scrollable area dynamically by mouse click after select the object type from the toolbar.

I need to prevent intersection the bounds of objects on scrollable area while user moving an object from one location to another.

Basically, I know that it is not difficult to check intersections by using intersect method of linq. However, there are lot of objects in the scrollable area in most cases. So, I have been thinking to find an efficent and fast logic to check possible intersects for n number of objects.

I would be pleased for your suggestions.

Thanks

I tried following method in MouseUp event (when user released object)

```
private bool IsIntersected(BaseNode movingControl)
{
    List<BaseNode> controls = (from x in Controls.Cast<Control>() 
                                                 .Where(x => x.GetType()
                                                 .IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseNode)))
                               select (BaseNode)x).ToList();

    if (controls.Count > 0 && controls.Contains(movingControl))
        controls.Remove(movingControl);

    foreach (BaseNode o in controls)
        if (o.DisplayRectangle.IntersectsWith(movingControl.DisplayRectangle))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would be pleased to see what you have tried.

Comment: It is an O(n) algorithm that runs at human-time.  Which lets you burn well over 50 *million* cpu cycles without the user noticing.  This is a classic case of premature optimization, you are trying to solve a problem that you don't actually have.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I am just thinking now.

Comment: Dear Passant, can you please post your opinion along with some explanations and document links (if exist). Regards

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each object is a Rectangle, it sounds as though you should process this exactly as gamedev does. There is ultimately no way around iterating each item (unless you go down the route of QuadTrees), but ultimately:

```
for(int i = 0; i<items.count();i++)
{
    var ob = items[i];

    for(int j = i+1;j<items.Count();j++)
    {
        if(ob.Rectangle.Intersects(items[j].rectangle))
        {
            //DO Somthing
        }
    }
}
```

I would beware of premature optimization as ultimately a modern CPU can handle this very quickly. In regards to handling the response of the collision, you would need to provide detail of what you wanted to occur if items intersected.